# Emacs term mode: Selecting word by double-clicking with mouse

Tags: select, emacs, mouse

How do I get a url to be selected by double-clicking in Emacs term mode?  For example, if I see stackoverflow.com in my terminal and I'd like to select it by double-clicking on it, it currently just selects either stackoverflow or com, but not stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

1. Double-click the dot (`.`) in `stackoverflow.com` to select all of that URL.

   Depending on the current mode, `.` might have *symbol* syntax and not *word* syntax.

   Double-clicking a *word*-constituent character selects the clicked *word*.
   Double-clicking a *symbol*-constituent character selects the clicked *symbol*.

   See the Elisp manual, node [Syntax Class Table](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html).
2. You can also click `mouse-3` on the last word to select (e.g. `com`), after double-clicking `mouse-1` on the first word to select (e.g. `stackoverflow`).

   See the Emacs manual, node [Mouse Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mouse-Commands.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can double-click on one word and then, keeping the button pressed, move the mouse to extend the selection by additional words.